# "Image size" ambiguous meaning, avoid repetition

Tags: terminology, languages

An image "size" can mean both the widthxheight or its weight. How could I edit this paragraph to not use the word 'size' twice?

> Allowed sizes: 300x250, 300x100
>
> Max size: 300KB

Comment: the first "size" is a resolution, the second one is a file size.

Comment: draw a clear line to separate the terms. Using 'resolution' and 'file size' can do that. The most important is not get your readers lost or confused.

Comment: but resolution is used more in photography, not much in advertising, these are banners and I never heard "banner resolution"

Comment: if you add more information about the use case - like you just did - will improve the answer you'll get. Could you give us more details?

Comment: Resolution isn't only used in photography, and it doesn't strike me as odd to say "Banner resolution". Even if you didn't know what a resolution was, it would be immediately obvious from the context because you display the possible resolutions right after.

Comment: The context is display advertising. For example Google uses "ad unit size" and "file size" in DFP: http://i.imgur.com/BGFQOAI.png

Comment: So use "dimensions" rather than "resolution".

Answer (score 1):

Don't. "size" is the accepted term for both file sizes and row/column counts. It's not worth deviating from standard terminology to fix a perceived style issue.